# How to store an ID number or Phone number as an integer without an error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im having a bit of trouble trying to store an ID number, or even a phone number as an Integer value.

This is what ive tried:

```
begin
  InfoFile := TStringList.Create;


    ID := StrToInt(edtID.Text);
    PhoneNumber := StrToInt(edtPhone.Text);
```

I keep on getting `***** is not a valid integer value`. First of all, I know the number is too big for an integer value, is there a way to compress or make it smaller somehow? Or should I just not use it as a variable? I dont really know if im making too much sense.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: There are so many [`different conventions`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers) used in many countries, that I wouldn't store phone numbers as numeric values. But it depends on if you want to use your application outside of your country and what is a phone number convention used in your country.

Comment: Seems you got your answer in using 64-bit integer. Just do not count that it will work all over the world, since you'll never be able to decode that integer to the format valid for a certain country (unless you store also what country is that phone from). Also you shouldn't put a unique constraint on that field because you may encode two numbers from different countries to the same 64-bit integer (assuming you're going to store it to a DB).

Comment: @TLama , thanks for the comment, just using it for Local to store in a text file.. If it should work on a DB, it should work in a text file right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be obvious that you cannot compress a phone number. Compression has to be reversible. If you could compress the number so that, for instance, you could store, say, a 40 bit value in 32 bits, then your compression would not be reversible. There are 2<sup>32</sup> distinct values that can be stored in a 32 bit value. If there are more than 
2<sup>32</sup> distinct telephone numbers, then compression cannot possibly help.

Probably the most expedient solution, if you must store as an integer, is to store the number as a 64 bit integer, [`Int64`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Int64). Convert from string using `StrToInt64`. The largest value that can be stored in a 64 bit integer is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

You will clearly need to sanitise your string before you attempt to call `StrToInt64`. You'll need to remove spaces, hyphens etc. And are you sure that you can store the number as an integer. For instance, I might write a UK telephone number as `+44 151 876 2765`. What will you do with the `+`?

So, whilst `Int64` gives you more range, you might wish to consider whether or not the value would be better stored in a string.

Comment: The StrToInt64 worked like a charm! Thanks dude. My problem with (Like your example on the phone number with the `+***` is that I also have a Date TEdit, where the user enters the date he joined. The date format required is `(yyyy/mm/dd)`. So for instance, how would I convert `2009/09/01` to an Integer or Real or what ever?

Comment: Convert string to date with `StrToDate`. Of course, that is something of a minefield when you consider all the possible formats. Make sure you use the overload of `StrToDate` that accepts a format settings variable.

Comment: Okay well, seeing as it only accepts one format of date, I can put a label next to the TEdit for the date, notifying the user that the specific date format must be used. Anyhow, how would I assign the/a date to be a variable? `Date : Date` or `Date : Integer`, Im fairly new with delphi7

Comment: Use `TDateTime` for a date. You might be handicapped by the fact that D7 uses a global variable for the format when converting. Personally, I'd write my own bespoke date string parser and then use `EncodeDate`.

Comment: Okay, all good! Got it working! I just said `Date : TDateTime;` and `Date := StrToDate(edtJoinDate.Text);` Thanks David. Oh and the Format is `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`. One of the two. I just tested it with `01/01/2009`

Comment: The format will vary from machine to machine. Read the docs for StrToDate carefully.

Comment: Haha, didnt realize the part with different machines.. Thanks for the advice :)